# Bluetooth obex reception on 3rd edition device fails

Tags: symbian, s60, pys60, s60-3rd-edition

I have got a mix of 2nd edition and 3rd edition s60 phones. I start custom obex listener on both phones using Python and try to send files to them. Though I can send files to 2nd edition phone; I can't send files to 3rd edition phone and the error being "Broken pipe".

Why this is so?

Comment: what actual transfer medium are you using? bluetooth or infrared? what specific phones and firmware versions are you using? what happens when you interact with a non-Series60 phone?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I added that I am using bluetooth. Its Pys60 therefore, s60 only.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Symbian C++ SDK the API of Bluetooth was changed between 2nd to 3rd edition phones.
It probably affects also Python.

Comment: But isn't PyS60 supposed to accommodate those changes?